# Magnetic and electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism

What happens to the magnetic and electric fields if we take a differentiable scalar field and redefine:
$$A^{\prime}=A + \nabla_{\varphi}$$

and

$$\phi^{\prime}=\phi -\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}$$

Comment: Have you tried plugging the new expressions into the fields to see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

It remains unchanged. Because the magnetic field B is the curl of the vector potential.

From the vector identity that the curl of gradient is zero, you can quite clearly see that the Magnetic field remains unchanged.

Guess what, even the electric field is unchanged.
What you have just discovered, my friend, is called Gauge invariance, which plays a very important role in particle physics.

Read more about it here :-

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory